# Boolean imprimindo apenas "true"

Tags: java, variáveis, booleano

Oii, gente. Em uma atividade para o curso estou fazendo uma atividade que utiliza diversos tipos de dados e tem operadores para comparar as variáveis. Porém, meu único problema chega a ser ridículo pq ao testar o código e escrever "false" para a cobertura, o programa ainda imprimi "true".
Alguém **por favor**, consegue me ajudar e apontar qual pode ser o erro?
Cansei de pesquisar com a professora e não conclui o que pode estar acontecendo.

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Digite o sabor: ");
      String sabor = sc1.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Digite a quantidade de xícaras de leite/oléo: ");
      double leite = sc1.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Digite a quantidade de xícaras de farinha de trigo ");
      double farinha = sc1.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Digite a quantidade de ovos: ");
      int ovo = sc1.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Com cobertura? True para sim ou False para Não: ");
      boolean cobertura = sc1.hasNextBoolean();
    System.out.println(" **** Sua receita **** ");
    System.out.println("Sabor: " + sabor);
    System.out.println("Quantidade de xícaras de leite/óleo: " + leite);
    System.out.println("Xícaras de farinha de trigo: " + farinha);
    System.out.println("Quantidade de ovos: " + ovo);
    System.out.println("Cobertura: " + cobertura);
  }
}
```

Comment: `hasNextBoolean` não é para PEGAR o próximo booleano e sim para VERIFICAR SE EXISTE um booleano a ser pego (seja True ou False). Se você puser "false" no input, o `hasNextBoolean` retorna "true" pois há de fato um booleano válido a ser pego. Para obter o valor de fato, você usa `nextBoolean`. - Atenção, note bem a diferença de grafia de ambos:  `nextBoolean` × `hasNextBoolean`

Comment: Oii Bacco, então a principio meu código estava com o  'nextBoolean' mas este não rodava com ele (comentamos ele no código e vimos que o problema estava ali). A solução foi inserir o 'hasNextBoolean'. E assim ele passou a rodar, porém não imprimia o valor que o usuário inseria.

Comment: Não consegui entender pq não roda com o 'nextBoolean' ainda, infelizmente. Mas consegui ajuda aqui para chegar em algo que me entregou o que eu queria. Muito obrigada pelas dicas, vou lembrar dela sempre que for utilizar boolean.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Ruth, não tenho certeza, mas creio que um valor boolean não pode ser definido da forma que você fez, ao invés disso, tente usar um if else no lugar, atribuindo o valor de sim ou não a um int e depois analisando ele.

Usando essa mesma estrutura sua, resolveria o problema assim:

```
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Digite o sabor: ");
    String sabor = sc1.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Digite a quantidade de xícaras de leite/oléo: ");
    double leite = sc1.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Digite a quantidade de xícaras de farinha de trigo ");
    double farinha = sc1.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Digite a quantidade de ovos: ");
    int ovo = sc1.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Com cobertura? [1] Sim ou [2] Não: ");
    int coberturaInt = sc1.nextInt();
    String cobertura = "";

    if (coberturaInt == 1) {
        cobertura = "Sim";
    } else if (coberturaInt == 2) {
        cobertura = "Não";
    }
    System.out.println(" **** Sua receita **** ");
    System.out.println("Sabor: " + sabor);
    System.out.println("Quantidade de xícaras de leite/óleo: " + leite);
    System.out.println("Xícaras de farinha de trigo: " + farinha);
    System.out.println("Quantidade de ovos: " + ovo);
    System.out.println("Cobertura: " + cobertura);
}
```

Porém, eu usaria JOptionPane, que facilita imensamente o trabalho e tornando-o mais visual, neste caso o código ficaria assim:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String sabor = "", cobertura = "";
        String[] coberturas = { "Chocolate", "Leite Ninho", "Chantilly", "Morango" };
        double leite, farinha;
        int ovo, coberturaInt;

        sabor = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite o sabor: ");
        leite = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite a quantidade de xícaras de leite/oléo: ")); //
        farinha = Double
                .parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite a quantidade de xícaras de farinha de trigo: ")); //
        ovo = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite a quantidade de ovos"));
        coberturaInt = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "O bolo terá cobertura?", "Cobertura", 1, -1, null,
                coberturas, coberturas[0]);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sabor: " + sabor + "\nQuantidade de xícaras de leite/óleo: " + leite
                + "\nXícaras de farinha de trigo: " + farinha + "\nQuantidade de ovos: " + ovo + "\n Cobertura: "
                + coberturas[coberturaInt], cobertura, coberturaInt);
    }
```

Dessa forma você diminui o código e a possibilidade de ter problemas como esse seu já que possível pré-definir os inputs possíveis do usuário.

Comment: Oi Eduardo, muito obrigada! Vou tentar fazer essas alterações e te conto se deu certo. Pois foi um problema real em sala de aula hahah

Comment: Oii, eu de novo! Deu super certo a primeira opção, MUITO obrigada. E quanto a segunda, vou precisar de ajuda na aula para compreender melhor pois ta um pouquinho complicado em comparação ao que sei por enquanto. Mas muito obrigada Eduardo, agora tudo está funcionando da maneira que eu desejava!